# How can I tell Entity Framework that cascading deletes will work

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework sees that there can be competing cascading deletes. However, in use it's impossible. I need to know how to tell Entity Framework this.

This app is to handle political volunteers and these volunteers can be helping at the state level, the county level and/or the campaign level.

1. Every state has a collection of counties & campaigns.
2. Every state, county, & campaign has a collection of events.
3. Every event has a parent/owner which is a state, county, or campaign. Only one of these is set for any given event.

I see two problems (maybe there's more).

1. If you trace from event up to its three owners, all three of those owners then have a collection of events.
2. If you trace from state, it has a collection of events, it also has collections of counties & campaigns, that each have a collection of events.

How can I tell Entity Framework and SQL Server that in operation there will not be two owners both trying to cascade delete the same event?

Associated question. In EventConfiguration.Configure, how can I tell the DB to enforce that for the three foreign keys, in any given record, exactly two of those FKs must be null?

The error I get running Update-Database is:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Events_Counties_CountyId' on table 'Events' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

[The solution is available as a zip here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwpna0fcuh558rf/CascadeDelete.zip?dl=1) Or you can view the classes below:

```
public class Campaign
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public required State State { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
    protected Campaign(int id, string name, DateTime created)
    {
        Id = id;
        Events = default!;
        Followers = default!;
    }
    public Campaign()
    {
        Events = new List<Event>();
        Followers = new List<User>();
    }
}

public class CampaignConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Campaign>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Campaign> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(new[] { "Name", "StateId" }).IsUnique();
        builder.HasIndex("StateId");
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Events)
            .WithOne(x => x.Campaign).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}


public class County
{
    public int Id { get; private set;  }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public required State State { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
    protected County(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Events = default!;
        Followers = default!;
    }
    public County()
    {
        Events = new List<Event>();
        Followers = new List<User>();
    }
}

public class CountyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<County>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<County> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(new[]{"Name", "StateId"}).IsUnique();
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Events)
            .WithOne(x => x.County).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}


public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public required User Owner { get; set; }
    public Campaign? Campaign { get; set; }
    public County? County { get; set; }
    public State? State { get; set; }
    protected Event(int id, DateTime created)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    public Event()
    {
    }
}

public class EventConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Event>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Event> builder)
    {
        // fails!
        // builder.HasIndex(e => new[] { "CampaignId", "CountyId", "StateId" }).IsUnique();
    }
}


public class State
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<County> Counties { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
    protected State(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Counties = default!;
        Campaigns = default!;
        Events = default!;
        Followers = default!;
    }
    public State()
    {
        Counties = new List<County>();
        Campaigns = new List<Campaign>();
        Events = new List<Event>();
        Followers = new List<User>();
    }
}

public class StateConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<State>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<State> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Counties)
            .WithOne(x => x.State).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Campaigns)
            .WithOne(x => x.State).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Events)
            .WithOne(x => x.State).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}


public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public ICollection<County> Counties { get; set; }
    public ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    protected User(int id, string name, string email)
    {
        Id = id;
        Campaigns = default!;
        Counties = default!;
        States = default!;
        Events = default!;
    }
    public User()
    {
        Campaigns = new List<Campaign>();
        Counties = new List<County>();
        States = new List<State>();
        Events = new List<Event>();
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
    }
}
```

**Update:**

According to @GertArnold and Chat-GPT, I can't set this up for a cascade delete. So, what if instead I allowed Event.Campaign, Event.County, and Event.State to all be null. And on a delete of a Campaign, County, or State I set the Event FK to null.

And then for cleanup, I then delete all Event records with all 3 set to null. Is that a good solution to this?

And if so, how do I tell EF to do so. I added the following:

```
public class CountyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<County>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<County> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Events)
            .WithOne(x => x.County).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}

public class EventConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Event>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Event> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Campaign)
            .WithMany(c => c.Events)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        builder.HasOne(e => e.County)
            .WithMany(c => c.Events)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        builder.HasOne(e => e.State)
            .WithMany(c => c.Events)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}
```

And on the command Update-Database I get:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Events_Counties_CountyId' on table 'Events' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

So what do I need to set to allow this. I also got the problem with no Fluent commands in the EventConfiguration as I thought it was only needed in Campaign, County, & State - but same error.

**Update 2:**

If I set OnDelete() to DeleteBehavior.Restrict then the DB builds fine and I can delete Campaign & County records (the Event records remain with the FK set to null).

But I fail on deleting a State record. Because it cascade deletes the Campaign & County records it owns and they fail on the Event records they point to:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Events_Campaigns_CampaignId". The conflict occurred in database "TestHoweState_2", table "dbo.Events", column 'CampaignId'.
```

where that constraint is:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Events",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        OwnerId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        CampaignId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
        CountyId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
        StateId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Events", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Events_Campaigns_CampaignId",
            column: x => x.CampaignId,
            principalTable: "Campaigns",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Events_Counties_CountyId",
            column: x => x.CountyId,
            principalTable: "Counties",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Events_States_StateId",
            column: x => x.StateId,
            principalTable: "States",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Events_Users_OwnerId",
            column: x => x.OwnerId,
            principalTable: "Users",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

Comment: *How can I tell Entity Framework and SQL Server*. It's a SQL server error and the short and only answer is: you can't.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you for the "can't do it" - saves me wasting more time trying. But now, accepting that, how can I null the FK entries in Event? I added an update to my question above because setting them to null doesn't appear to work either. TIA